# Django blog comment functionality with Jquery not working, takes me to JSON page instead

Tags: jquery, django

So i am building a blog with Django and I am trying to implement a comment functionality with JQuery to avoid a page refresh. I've written the codes but when I click on the comment submit button, I get sent to a white page with JSON data. I've struggled with this problem for too long and i'm hoping for a solution here. Following are the relevant codes.

in my detail page, this is the html for the comment form:

```
<div id="comment-container" class="comment-container" style="display: none;">
                      <form id="comment-form" method="post" action="{% url 'article:comment_submit' post.slug %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <textarea id="comment-textarea"
                        style="font-size: 16px; color: #333; background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #ccc; 
                        border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px; outline: none; text-align:left;" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
                        </textarea>
                        <button id="submit-comment" style="display: block;" type="button">Submit</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
```

still in my detail page is an empty div tag where I intend to prepend/append the comments:

```
<div id="comments-section">
                    </div>
```

in my main.js, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Function to submit the comment form using AJAX
    $("#submit-comment").on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      var commentText = $("#comment-textarea").val().trim();
      if (commentText !== "") {
        var formData = $("#comment-form").serialize();
        // Get the comment submission URL from the data attribute
        var commentSubmitURL = "{% url 'article:comment_submit' post.slug %}";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: commentSubmitURL,
          data: formData,
          success: function(response) {
            // Clear the comment textarea after successful submission
            $("#comment-textarea").val("");
            // Render the new comment on the page
            renderComment(response);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
    });

    // Function to render a new comment on the page
    function renderComment(commentData) {
      var commentHtml = `
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment-header">
            <h3>${commentData.user}</h3>
            <span class="timestamp">${commentData.date_posted}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-body">
            <p>${commentData.comment}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-footer">
            <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
            <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
            <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="child-comments">
            <!-- Child comments go here (if any) -->
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
      $("#comments-section").append(commentHtml);
    }
  });
```

for my python codes, the following are the relevant ones. In my models.py, I have:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', default='uncategorized')
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="post_likes")
    is_edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in my urls.py, I have:

```
path('comment_submit/<str:slug>/', views.comment_submit, name='comment_submit'),
```

in my views.py, I have:

```
def comment_submit(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the comment data from the request and save it to the database
        comment_text = request.POST.get('comment')
        # Assuming you have already authenticated the user
        user = request.user
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=user, comment=comment_text)
        comment_data = {
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'comment': comment.comment,
        }
        return JsonResponse(comment_data)
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'})
```

Please why does it not work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by switching from JQuery to the FETCH API. in my views.py, I have -

```
@require_POST
@login_required
def comment_submit(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the comment data from the request and save it to the database
        comment_text = request.POST.get('comment')
        # Assuming you have already authenticated the user
        user = request.user
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=user, comment=comment_text)
        comment_data = {
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'comment': comment.comment,
        }
        return JsonResponse(comment_data)
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'})
```

in my main.js i have -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Function to submit the comment form using Fetch API
  document.getElementById("comment-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

    var commentText = document.getElementById("comment-textarea").value.trim();
    if (commentText !== "") {
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      var slug = this.getAttribute("data-slug");
      var commentSubmitURL = `/comment_submit/${slug}/`;

      fetch(commentSubmitURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Clear the comment textarea after successful submission
        document.getElementById("comment-textarea").value = "";
        // Render the new comment on the page
        renderComment(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
    }
  });

  // Function to render a new comment on the page
function renderComment(commentData) {
  var commentHtml = `
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <h3>${commentData.user}</h3>
      <span class="timestamp">${commentData.date_posted}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <p>${commentData.comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-footer">
      <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
      <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
      <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child-comments">
      <!-- Child comments go here (if any) -->
    </div>
  </div>`;

  document.getElementById("comments-section").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", commentHtml);
}

  // Function to get CSRF token from cookies
  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + "=")) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }
});
```

and that fixed it. Although the added comments do not persist, but that should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

`#submit-comment` is a button and you are preventing click event on that button.
Instead you need to prevent the default form submit event.

So, change `$("#submit-comment").on("click", function(event)`
to:
`$("#comment-form").on("submit", function(event)`

Also, change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

Comment: I tried what you said and the problem persists. After clicking on the submit button I get sent to a white page with Json data. The page has {"user": "name of user", "date_posted" : "date posted", "comment": "The comment that was submitted". I'm lost at this point.

Comment: I commented out the JQuery comment functionality code and clicked on the comment submit button and still got sent to the white page with JSON data. It appears there's a problem somewhere unrelated to the JQUERY code which I cant find